# Finding Links from Web DAV

Tags: webdav

Does anyone know of a way in which I can obtain the URL of a file if I am using the Windows Explorer or Web DAV view of a document library. So far I can only get the link by either the browser version or if I actually open the file in Office etc...

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Windows Explorer view **is** WebDAV (and relies on activeX technology in the IE 32 bit browser, so not available in other browsers or IE 64-bit windows)

```
NET USE
```

Will not show the URL,
but if you open a command-prompt it will show the current path

So you need to use the drive letter from the CD command to get the server name from NET USE, the CD path is the server path

FYI, Connections are stored in the Credentials Manager

```
rundll32.exe keymgr.dll, KRShowKeyMgr
```

And they are persistent... you can be logded off from SharePoint but still have access tru WebDAV (OMG Governance nightmare)